# style.css does'nt find in my app node js /express

Tags: css, node.js, express

I work on a app node js / express and my browser doesn'nt find my style.css however i use a static file

Here is my tree :

public -> css -> styles.css

server -> server.js

views ->layout -> header.ejs

in heade.ejs :

```
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/asset/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
```

in my server.js :

```
// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(session({
secret: 'kfhkhkgfkgfkhgjdkdkk',
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: true,
cookie: { secure: false }
}));
app.use(require('./middlewares/flash'));
app.use('/asset', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

thank you for your futur help ;)

Comment: Cannot GET /asset/css/style.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have issue with the directory structure. You have `server.js` in server folder, that's why following line is not working.

```
app.use('/asset', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Try the following code where we have joined the path of `public` directory relative to `server` folder.

```
var path = require('path');
app.use('/asset', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here is my tree :

public -> css -> styles.css

href="/**asset**/css/style.css">

Try href="css/style.css">

Comment: always nothing :(

Comment: always nothing?  What does this mean?  Please explain.

Comment: always same problem 404 not found for my file css